# MVC 5 Is AntiForgeryToken needed when using Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I am building an MVC 5 app with Windows Authentication and I am wondering if I need the `AntiForgeryToken` on top of this?

I can't do a simple GET request with fiddler as it returns Unauthorized. I assume I do not need the token?

Answer (score 2):

Normally you do not set `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` on GET requests. You can use Windows Authentication to authenticate and `Authorize` to let users in. When you POST to the server, it is a good idea to validate the token to make sure the form actually came from the server.